# Using jQuery, How can I remove classes on clicking anywhere except an ID?

Tags: jquery

I have this code. It opens a sidebar on clicking a button. I also added a remove class function that'll remove the class on clicking any part of the page including the sidebar itself.

```
$(function(){ 
    $("#users, #close-user").click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        $("#user-list").addClass("open");
    });
    $(document).click(function(){
            if( $("#user-list").hasClass("open") ){
            $("#user-list").removeClass("open");
        };
    });
});
```

How can I modify this code so that the sidebar will close only when I click on any other element other than the sidebar?

Comment: uhm ... something like `$('body *:not(#user-list)').on('click', function...)`?

Comment: @SpYk3HH tried that, it is not working :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).closest('#user-list').length) {
        $("#user-list").addClass("open");
    }else{
        $("#user-list").removeClass("open");
    }
});
```

You shouldn't use `event.stopPropagation();` as told [here](http://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/)

> Modifying a single, fleeting event might seem harmless at first, but it comes with risks. When you alter the behavior that people expect and that other code depends on, you're going to have bugs. It's just a matter of time.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4kx10sn3/)

Comment: OK, this is working. I'll choose this as an answer in 7 more minutes. Thanks for the information.

Comment: How can I get rid of `event.stopPropagation();`. I don't understand.

Comment: @Sam I added a JSFiddle to the answer

Comment: `$('html').click(function()` doesn't work in firefox only. Works nicely in chrome and opera. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Sam Firefox seems to require the `event` argument in the function so change your code to `$('html').click(function(event)`

Answer (score 1):

You can `stopPropagation` on click of sliderbar. Like this:

```
$('#user-list').click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: In the code that I have pasted, there is already a `e.stopPropagation();`.

Comment: @sam: you need to do same stuff on click of sidebar.